# Imprimir multiples etiquetas en un solo documento

Tags: c#, windows-forms, impresión

Estoy tratando de generar una serie de etiquetas e imprimirlas,
el número de etiquetas y sus datos son obtenidos de una tabla `Sql` a través de una consulta.
La idea es recorrer el `dataTable` que me retorna la consulta e imprimir una etiqueta por cada `row`.
El problema es que al imprimir no consigo que me añada una página por cada etiqueta al documento, sino que machaca siempre la misma.

Para explicar un poco el código, en un formulario tengo el diseño de la etiqueta, `panels` para dibujar marco y líneas y `textboxs` para los datos y literales.
Cuando imprimo, recorro estos controles para montar la etiqueta y extraigo los datos de cada uno de los `txtbox` a imprimir con `GetCellData()`.

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    DataTable data = GetData();
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    BarcodeLib.Barcode barcode = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();
    Image barcode1 = barcode.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128, "TestCodi", Color.Black, Color.White,txt28.Width -10,txt28.Height -10);

    pd.DefaultPageSettings = new PageSettings()
    {
        PaperSize = new PaperSize() { RawKind = (int)PaperKind.A4 },
        Landscape = false,
        PrinterResolution = new PrinterResolution() { X = 300, Y = 300 },
        Margins = new Margins(10, 10, 0, 0)
    };
    pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings() { PrinterName = printer.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, };
    List<TextBox> lData = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x=>x.Tag != null).Where(x=> x.Tag.GetType()== typeof(tipusField)).Where(x=>(tipusField)x.Tag==tipusField.Data).ToList();
    List<TextBox> lLabel = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x => x.Tag != null).Where(x=> x.Tag.GetType() == typeof(tipusField)).Where(x => (tipusField)x.Tag == tipusField.Label).ToList();
    List<TextBox> lBarCode = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x => x.Tag != null).Where(x => x.Tag.GetType() == typeof(tipusField)).Where(x => (tipusField)x.Tag == tipusField.Barcode).ToList();
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler((object o, PrintPageEventArgs e) =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            PrintLines(this, e);
            lData.ForEach((x =>
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(GetCellData(x.Text, data.Rows[i]), x.Font, Brushes.Black, ObtainRectangle(x), Alineament(x));
            }));
            lLabel.ForEach((x =>
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(x.Text, x.Font, Brushes.Black, ObtainRectangle(x), Alineament(x));
            }));
            lBarCode.ForEach((x =>
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(barcode1, ObtainRectangle(x, 5, 10));
            }));
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), new Rectangle(this.panelMarc.Location.X, this.panelMarc.Location.Y, this.panelMarc.Width, this.panelMarc.Height));
            if (i == data.Rows.Count - 1)
                e.HasMorePages = false;
            else
                e.HasMorePages = true;
        }
    });
    printer.Document = pd;
    pd.Print();
}
```

¿Alguien me puede echar una mano por favor?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: No entendi la pregunta.

Comment: Por cada registro del dataTable, he de generar una etiqueta, de ahí el for() pero por muchos registros que tenga el datatable, solo me imprime un documento de una sola página.